# UITextView setSelectedRange issue

Tags: uitextview, placeholder, nsrange

I have subclassed `UITextView` with the goal of introducing `placeholder` functionality. It's mostly working well, but I'm having issue with the behaviour when the `UITextView` becomes active either by user tap or by calling `becomeFirstResponder`. Below is the custom method that gets called whenever a `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification gets fired.

```
- (void)textViewSelected {

    if ([self.text isEqualToString:self.placeholder]) {

        NSLog(@"a %@", NSStringFromRange(self.selectedRange));
        self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
        NSLog(@"b %@", NSStringFromRange(self.selectedRange));
    }
}
```

Console logs this

```
a {16, 0}
b {0, 0}
```

but the cursor is still blinking here

[image]

I even tried subclassing `the setSelectedRange:` method to check if something sets the range after my method call

```
- (void)setSelectedRange:(NSRange)selectedRange {

    NSLog(@"aa %@", NSStringFromRange(self.selectedRange));
    [super setSelectedRange:selectedRange];
    NSLog(@"bb %@", NSStringFromRange(self.selectedRange));
}
```

But the result if as follows:

```
a {16, 0}
aa {16, 0}
bb {0, 0}
b {0, 0}
```

which would imply that the cursor should be at index 0.

Anyone has any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't sort out why `NSMakeRange(0, 0)` didn't work, but I ended up solving my problem by calling `NSMakeRange(0, 0)` with a delay, like so:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(placeMarkerInTheBeginning) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

And

```
- (void)placeMarkerInTheBeginning {

    self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Had the same issue - had to put a tiny delay before triggering  `setSelectedRange:` and that seemed to work.